# WooCommerce, insert multiple products

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Im using the WooCommerce plugin to WordPress and i have to insert like 1000 products in one category. But all this products have the same name. Do i have Any method to insert multiple products at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It can have the same name, and be in the same category as well. 
The SKU number should just be unique.
Create a page manually.
Use Woocommerce shortcodes : eg:

```
[products skus="

SKU1000
,SKU1001
,SKU1002
,SKU1003

" orderby="sku" order="asc" ]
```

This should work, hope it helps.